# Playstore notification in Android unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier interface

Tags: android-security

We have developed the app and published the google play store then received the notification from Google like as following.

'We found that your app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for users. Apps with these vulnerabilities can expose user information or damage a user’s device, and may be considered to be in violation of our Malicious Behavior policy'
'Your app(s) are using an unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier interface. You can find more information about how resolve the issue in this'

We need to resolve this before the deadline 1 January 2021.

Please, help me how to solve this issue?

Comment: HI, did you find any solution to it?

Comment: No yet. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Nope, I have a deadline of 23 December, Tried every possible solution on the stack but still no help.